# How to get an animated underline effect in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, underline

I am designing my personal website for the very first time using Bootstrap. I think it would be an amazing learning experience. I have used Jekyll in the past but I ended up learning very little out of that.

For my website, I'd like to use the **animated underline** seen at http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/ when you hover over 'Source' or 'View on Github'. I tried looking for it at places but could not find it as I'm not sure if I am searching for the right things.

I would appreciate it if someone showed me a way to write this. I am assuming CSS would be used for such an effect.

Thank you.

Comment: A huge milestone in your path as a web developer is learning how to use and read the developer's console in your browser - it will give you all the information you need to determine how that animation is done.

Comment: Sorry, we don't write the code for you. We help with code that is written. Make an attempt yourself. Give us some html at least to start with and anything else you have tried. Start by viewing the source of the page you link to and work from there.

Comment: [Here's a hint](http://imgur.com/L9SUmH9).

Comment: http://stas-melnikov.ru/hovers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m91p2r6c/1/) help you to find a way. It uses only the CSS to animate.

```
<h3 class="sliding-middle-out">Underline – Middle Out</h3>
.sliding-middle-out {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-middle-out:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The author of the site you shared actually wrote a blog post on this exact thing. It can be done fairly easily. [Here](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/) is his blog post showing step by step how to do it. Next time try searching around and see what you can find (this is the first link when you google "animated underline effect in html").

Answer (score 1):

There's an explanation and demonstration here:

[removed - source code is below]

And the code from  the page is thus (this is a whole example of a page that you can copy into a file and run):

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div#menubar {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        div#menubar span {
            display:inline-block;
            margin: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
        }

        div#menubar span::after {
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          top: 3px;
          content: '';
          border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
          transform: scaleX(0);  
          transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
        }

        div#menubar span:hover::after {
            transform: scaleX(1);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="menubar">
        <span>Item 1</span>
        <span>Item 2</span>
        <span>Item 3</span>
        <span>Item 4</span>
        <span>Item 5</span>
        <span>Item 6</span>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```